# What is causing a crash in my c++ JNI?

Tags: android, c++, android-ndk, java-native-interface, cocos2d-x

I'm trying to implement facebook login in my c++ class. From java I am trying to get facebook information of user. Everything is passed correctly from Java to C++.

**However, when this piece of code is uncommented**, my application crashes with signal 11 (memory issue according to other similar answers here)

```
    JNIEXPORT void JNICALL Java_com_humit_android_HumIt_javaCallJNI(JNIEnv* env, jobject obj,
                                        jstring javaString1, jstring javaString2, jstring javaString3)
{
    //Get the native string from javaString
     const char *nativeString1 = env->GetStringUTFChars(javaString1, 0);
     const char *nativeString2 = env->GetStringUTFChars(javaString2, 0);
     const char *nativeString3 = env->GetStringUTFChars(javaString3, 0);
```

> // below 2 lines are giving error... if commented, no problem...!

```
    LoginScreen * loginScreen = new LoginScreen();
    loginScreen->facebookProfileInfoFetch("hi", "hii", "hii");




    env->ReleaseStringUTFChars(javaString1, nativeString1);
    env->ReleaseStringUTFChars(javaString2, nativeString2);
    env->ReleaseStringUTFChars(javaString3, nativeString3);

}
```

The facebookProfileInfoFetch is:

```
void LoginScreen::facebookProfileInfoFetch(const char * value1, const char * value2, const char * value3) {
LOGD(" ----------------- facebookProfileInfoFetch ------------- %s ------------ ", value1);
LOGD(" ----------------- facebookProfileInfoFetch ------------- %s ------------ ", value2);
LOGD(" ----------------- facebookProfileInfoFetch ------------- %s ------------ ", value3);

facebookUserName = value1;
facebookUserId = value2;
facebookUserGender = value3;

this->loginHumServer();

}
```

It is crashing when loginHumServer() is called:

loginhumserver() is:

```
void LoginScreen::loginHumServer()
{
LOGD(" ----------------- loginHumServer ------------------------- ");
facebookDataRetrievedCount++;

if(facebookDataRetrievedCount<2)
    return;


CCHttpRequest* request = new CCHttpRequest();
LOGD(" ----------------- constructing url ------------------------- ");
std::string url="http://humsrer.co.in/user/sign_in?";
url=url+"name"+"="+facebookNoSpaceUserName+"&";
url=url+"facebook_thumbnail"+"="+facebookUserPictureUrl+"&";
url=url+"facebook_id"+"="+facebookUserId+"&";
url=url+"gender"+"="+facebookUserGender+"&";
url=url+"ios_push_id"+"="+"12346";

CCLog("UUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUU %s ",url.c_str());
request->setUrl(url.c_str());
request->setRequestType(CCHttpRequest::kHttpGet);
request->setResponseCallback(this, callfuncND_selector(LoginScreen::onHttpRequestCompleted));
// optional fields
request->setTag("GET test2");
LOGD(" ----------------- loginHumServer getInstance ------------------------- ");
CCHttpClient::getInstance()->send(request);

// don't forget to release it, pair to new
request->release();
LOGD(" ----------------- loginHumServer request->release ------------------------- ");
loginLabel->setString("Loging to hum server..");
}
```

This is the logcat error that I get when the app crashes:

```
 12-06 13:49:45.380: INFO/DEBUG(5637): signal 11 (SIGSEGV), code 1 (SEGV_MAPERR), fault addr deadbaad
12-06 13:49:45.380: INFO/DEBUG(5637):  r0 deadbaad  r1 01ddc9e8  r2 40000000  r3 00000000
12-06 13:49:45.380: INFO/DEBUG(5637):  r4 00000000  r5 00000027  r6 00000000  r7 57797f3c
12-06 13:49:45.380: INFO/DEBUG(5637):  r8 5c6d9c10  r9 57797f34  10 00000008  fp 5c6d9c24
12-06 13:49:45.380: INFO/DEBUG(5637):  ip ffffffff  sp 5c6d9a90  lr 400ff649  pc 400fb9d8  cpsr 60000030
12-06 13:49:45.380: INFO/DEBUG(5637):  d0  4448000044480000  d1  0000000000000000
12-06 13:49:45.380: INFO/DEBUG(5637):  d2  449a0000449a0000  d3  000004d0c41a0000
12-06 13:49:45.380: INFO/DEBUG(5637):  d4  3f8000004b7fffff  d5  449a000044480000
12-06 13:49:45.380: INFO/DEBUG(5637):  d6  4499e0004447c000  d7  0000000000000000
12-06 13:49:45.380: INFO/DEBUG(5637):  d8  0000000000000000  d9  0000000000000000
12-06 13:49:45.380: INFO/DEBUG(5637):  d10 0000000000000000  d11 0000000000000000
12-06 13:49:45.380: INFO/DEBUG(5637):  d12 0000000000000000  d13 0000000000000000
12-06 13:49:45.380: INFO/DEBUG(5637):  d14 0000000000000000  d15 0000000000000000
12-06 13:49:45.380: INFO/DEBUG(5637):  d16 5000000000000000  d17 0000000000000000
12-06 13:49:45.380: INFO/DEBUG(5637):  d18 0000000000000000  d19 0000000000000000
12-06 13:49:45.380: INFO/DEBUG(5637):  d20 0000000000000000  d21 0000000000000000
12-06 13:49:45.380: INFO/DEBUG(5637):  d22 0000000000000000  d23 0000000000000000
12-06 13:49:45.380: INFO/DEBUG(5637):  d24 0000000000000000  d25 0000000000000000
12-06 13:49:45.380: INFO/DEBUG(5637):  d26 0000000000000000  d27 0000000000000000
12-06 13:49:45.380: INFO/DEBUG(5637):  d28 0000000000000000  d29 0000000000000000
12-06 13:49:45.380: INFO/DEBUG(5637):  d30 0000000000000000  d31 0000000000000000
12-06 13:49:45.380: INFO/DEBUG(5637):  scr 60000010
12-06 13:49:45.650: INFO/DEBUG(5637):          #00  pc 000179d8  /system/lib/libc.so
12-06 13:49:45.650: INFO/DEBUG(5637):          #01  pc 0001ef44  /system/lib/libc.so (__assert2)
12-06 13:49:45.650: INFO/DEBUG(5637):          #02  pc 000fb552  /data/data/com.humit/lib/libgame.so (_ZN11LoginScreen22onHttpRequestCompletedEPN7cocos2d6CCNodeEPv)
12-06 13:49:45.655: INFO/DEBUG(5637):          #03  pc 001c3e32  /data/data/com.humit/lib/libgame.so (_ZN7cocos2d9extension12CCHttpClient25dispatchResponseCallbacksEf)
12-06 13:49:45.655: INFO/DEBUG(5637):          #04  pc 000ff9aa  /data/data/com.humit/lib/libgame.so (_ZN7cocos2d7CCTimer6updateEf)
12-06 13:49:45.655: INFO/DEBUG(5637):          #05  pc 001053d6  /data/data/com.humit/lib/libgame.so (_ZN7cocos2d11CCScheduler6updateEf)
12-06 13:49:45.655: INFO/DEBUG(5637):          #06  pc 0012f7f8  /data/data/com.humit/lib/libgame.so (_ZN7cocos2d10CCDirector9drawSceneEv)
12-06 13:49:45.660: INFO/DEBUG(5637):          #07  pc 00130df8  /data/data/com.humit/lib/libgame.so (_ZN7cocos2d21CCDisplayLinkDirector8mainLoopEv)
12-06 13:49:45.660: INFO/DEBUG(5637):          #08  pc 0016c66c  /data/data/com.humit/lib/libgame.so (Java_org_cocos2dx_lib_Cocos2dxRenderer_nativeRender)
12-06 13:49:45.660: INFO/DEBUG(5637):          #09  pc 0001ed70  /system/lib/libdvm.so (dvmPlatformInvoke)
12-06 13:49:45.660: INFO/DEBUG(5637):          #10  pc 0005902c  /system/lib/libdvm.so (_Z16dvmCallJNIMethodPKjP6JValuePK6MethodP6Thread)
```

I'm unable to debug why it is crashing. Kindly help.

**EDIT**
I have added onHttpRequestCompleted method:

```
void LoginScreen::onHttpRequestCompleted(CCNode *sender, void *data)
{
    LOGD(" ----------------- LoginScreen onHttpRequestCompleted ------------------------- ");
    CCLOG("request completed");

    CCHttpResponse *response = (CCHttpResponse*)data;

    if (!response)
    {
        LOGD(" ----------------- LoginScreen onHttpRequestCompleted return ------------------------- ");
        return;
    }

    // You can get original request type from: response->request->reqType
    if (0 != strlen(response->getHttpRequest()->getTag()))
    {
        CCLog("%s completed", response->getHttpRequest()->getTag());
    }

    int statusCode = response->getResponseCode();
    char statusString[64] = {};
    sprintf(statusString, "HTTP Status Code: %d, tag = %s", statusCode, response->getHttpRequest()->getTag());
    //m_labelStatusCode->setString(statusString);
    CCLog("response code: %d", statusCode);

    if (!response->isSucceed())
    {
        CCLog(" %s response failed", response->getResponseData());
        CCLog("error buffer: %s", response->getErrorBuffer());
        LOGD(" ----------------- LoginScreen onHttpRequestCompleted response failed ------------------------- ");
        return;
    }

     //dump data
    std::vector<char> *buffer = response->getResponseData();

    char * charbuffer = new char[buffer->size()];

    printf("Http Test, dump data: ");

    unsigned int size=0;
    for (unsigned int i = 0; i < buffer->size(); i++)
    {
        charbuffer[i] = (*buffer)[i];
        size=i+1;
    }

    charbuffer[size] = 0;

    char *errorPos = 0;
    char *errorDesc = 0;
    int errorLine = 0;
    block_allocator allocator(1 << 10); // 1 KB per block

    json_value *root = json_parse(charbuffer, &errorPos, &errorDesc, &errorLine, &allocator);

    root = root->first_child;

    assert(root->type ==JSON_STRING );

    assert(std::string(root->name) == "user_id" );

    loginLabel->setString("Loading active games..");
    GameManager::create(root->json_value::string_value,facebookUserId.c_str(),facebookUserName.c_str());

//  GameManager::create("b37e329c-37ac-11e2-abf1-1231381a9805");

    delete[] charbuffer;

    this->next();

}
```

Comment: what happen if no java at all, is the C++ function working correctly if called from c++ with the same parameter?

Comment: @MinLin thanks, but it is giving me the same error :(

Answer (score 1):

An assert() is firing.  You're failing at a very specific address:

```
INFO/DEBUG(5637): signal 11 (SIGSEGV), code 1 (SEGV_MAPERR), fault addr deadbaad
```

`0xdeadbaad` is used by the bionic abort() function.  (Not everyone likes this -- see http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=16672 .)

The stack trace tells you where you're failing:

```
INFO/DEBUG(5637):          #00  pc 000179d8  /system/lib/libc.so
INFO/DEBUG(5637):          #01  pc 0001ef44  /system/lib/libc.so (__assert2)
INFO/DEBUG(5637):          #02  pc 000fb552  /data/data/com.humit/lib/libgame.so (_ZN11LoginScreen22onHttpRequestCompletedEPN7cocos2d6CCNodeEPv)
INFO/DEBUG(5637):          #03  pc 001c3e32  /data/data/com.humit/lib/libgame.so (_ZN7cocos2d9extension12CCHttpClient25dispatchResponseCallbacksEf)
```

Note `__assert2`, defined in bionic's <assert.h>.

It's being called from `LoginScreen::onHttpRequestCompleted(cocos2d::CCNode*, void*)`.  You can use an address-to-line tool with the symbols from the library to convert that to a specific line number, but ideally the failing assertion itself will appear in logcat just above the native crash.

Answer (score 0):

You have a pointer somewhere which points to an invalid location. This is what's causing the segmentation fault. Seems like the crash starts in `LoginScreen::onHttpRequestCompleted`. Can you post that?

Comment: Can you run addr2line for 000fb552 in  /data/data/com.humit/lib/libgame.so? I have a feeling that this is being caused by the delete[]. Also, you don't need to manually copy over the char array, just do `char* charbuffer = &(*buffer)[0]` and (im pretty sure) you can drop the delete if you do that.

Comment: @llya O - ok i wl try that... if thats causing problems, y only when I  uncomment? y not while those lines r commented? if I comment those 2 lines everything else works fine...